# MFMailComposerController

Tags: mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am new to iphone. I want to use `MFMailComposer` please guide me how to use. I am not getting any right way to do. If so please give the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try [this](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/samplecode/MailComposer/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008865) sample code its pretty easy